# How can you pre-bake coca (pizza)?

Tags: pizza, spanish-cuisine

The [Spanish coca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca_%28pastry%29) is related to the pizza, so I guess the question can apply for both.

Normally I bake it in about 20 minute, should I take it out after 10 minute or later or sooner?

If I freeze it, can it be popped straight into the oven or should it be thawed first?

**Edit:** I've posted an answer below. Still wondering if you can take the pizza out of the freezer, put the filling on and pop it straight into the oven...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I bake it in about 20'..."? It sounds like you are talking about time but I am unfamiliar with ' used in the context of time. Are we talking about minutes? Or are we not talking about time at all?

Comment: @Jay My guess would be minutes, as in angle measurement ' is used to mark minutes (1/60 of a degree)

Comment: @Yamikuronue: Yea that makes sense. Thanks. BaffledCook, I made the edit to the question so there is no confusion. If you did mean something else, I guess edit it farther.

Comment: The `'` is used in many contexts to indicate minutes Races are an example.

Comment: @Jay, sorry, yes ' stands for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, pizza's can be pre-baked up to 80% of the normal baking time. People recommend:

- Baking without the filling (as this can make the base soggy).
- The filling should be pre-baked (otherwise the base will burn when finishing).

I've pre-baked 10 individual coca's and they're frozen. I'll report back how they turn out of the oven.

**Edit:** I did two straight out of the freezer, fresh ingredients. It worked pretty well, but not perfect (a little bit soggy). I'm guessing this was because the coca's were only 50% pre-baked.

Answer (score 1):

Did this for a lunch-rush special, prebaking individual pizzas (not thin-crust) in a slower oven with steam from a lg pan of water below.

Crusts were not at all brown nor crisp. Mushrooms cheese and other quick-cooking toppings needed no precooking.

A final assembled 5min high-heat crisping up was all that was needed.

I froze extra crusts but thawed them before use so no telling if freezer-to-oven is doable.